# iOS GKSession Stop Searching Devices after a while of time

Tags: objective-c, gksession

I want to develop an app that can send data between 2 or more iOS devices using bluetooth or wifi. I find GameKit framework can help me do that. My problems are:

1. How can I stop searching devices process after a while of time without any devices found?
   I've implemented GKPeerPickerController and when I press my button it will start searching devices process. I want after 10 seconds if there is no devices found, I will stop searching and notify user that there's no devices near here.
2. How can I specified that time for myself?
   Is there any property for me to set for the time like 10 seconds I indicated above.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that I can manage connection with GKSession, it doesn't need to use GKPeerPickerController. Just set property "available" of GKSession to YES or NO to start or stop searching devices to connect.